# How do I download log4j on ec2 instance?

Tags: linux, download, amazon-ec2

The link to download log4j is [here](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/logging/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.tar.gz). However I have logged into the my EC2 instance. Whats the command line to download this log4j ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `wget` to download the file:

```
wget http://www.eu.apache.org/dist/logging/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.tar.gz
```

You can change the `eu` to `us` in the URL to use the US mirror.

Also, consider using your package manager to install log4j instead; unless you have a specific requirement to download and install manually.

You've not mentioned which Linux distro you're running, but I know `lib4j` is available on Ubuntu and RedHat/CentOS.

For Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install log4j
```

For RedHat/CentOS:

```
$ sudo yum install log4j
```

Change `log4j` to `log4j-manual` and/or `log4j-javadoc` in the commands above for the developer manual and API documentation respectively.

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu, the package name is `liblog4j2-java`, so to install it using `apt-get` would be:

```
$ sudo apt-get install liblog4j2-java
```

For RedHat/CentOS as said in other answers would be:

```
$ sudo yum install log4j
```